# List docker containers by App using command line tool

Tags: docker, containers

How can I list docker containers by application? For example, assume that I have app1 (that has c1, c2, c3) and app2 (that has c4, c5) deployed. I can see c1, c2 and c3 are under app1 and c4 and c5 are under app2 using docker dashboard.  But, if I do "docker ps", it returns a flat list of containers, I have no way to know which containers belong to which app? Below is an example.

[image]

As can be seen in docker dashboard on the left side, there are two applications, nginx-gohttp-master and demo, deployed in the docker environment. The first app has two containers and the second app has four containers, and the two apps are independent of each other. However, I only see a flat list of containers on the right side as listed by "docker ps". I would like to know how many apps are deployed and which containers belong to which app. How can I do that using a docker command line tool?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by app? **A.** The image a container is based on (`IMAGE` column in `docker ps`) or **B.** you mean name/alias of container (`NAMES` column in `docker ps`)

Comment: om-ha, thanks for your reply. please see the image attached.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `docker-compose` adds some [labels](https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/) including `com.docker.compose.project` which contains the name of the compose app/project.  You can get that output using `docker ps` with the [`--format` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting) like so:

```
$ docker ps --format 'table {{.Label "com.docker.compose.project"}} {{.ID}} {{.Names}} {{.Command}} {{.Status}}'
project CONTAINER ID NAMES COMMAND STATUS
app1 1fd93328e69b app1_nginx_1 "/docker-entrypoint.…" Up 3 minutes
app2 9fe81391b961 app2_nginx_1 "/docker-entrypoint.…" Up 2 minutes
app3 d28fca61a184 app3_nginx_1 "/docker-entrypoint.…" Up 1 minutes
```

You can see some of the other labels that `docker-compose` applies [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/const.py#L11).

Comment: Great answer! I was formulating the command for this problem myself, but wouldn't have created a command like yours.

Comment: Kthompso, Thanks for your reply. I tried your command on my machine, but the following error occured. I am using Windows 10. Any thought? C:\Users\BlueStart>docker ps --format 'table {{.Label "com.docker.compose.project"}} {{.ID}} {{.Names}} {{.Command}} {{.Status}}'
"docker ps" accepts no arguments.
See 'docker ps --help'.

Usage:  docker ps [OPTIONS]

List containers

Comment: Okay, it runs in cygwin. Thanks a lot,  Kthompso! I am also wondering if there is docker command for this purpose (without formulating formulating the option part myself)

Comment: Good answer, `--format` data rather than just `--filter` it.

Comment: "_I am also wondering if there is docker command for this purpose  (without formulating formulating the option part myself)_"
 @D.Wang The concept of a docker app in this context is managed by docker-compose.  I don't believe docker itself has any concept of what containers are organized together.  docker-compose has similar commands like `ps`, but they run in the context of a single application AFAIK, so you would not get a host-wide view of your containers.  I think your best options is to create an alias or shell script for reuse.  If you use docker swarm you have more options.  Cheers.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again, Kthompso!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [filters](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering)

1. Filter running containers

```
docker ps --filter "name=nginx-gohttp-master"
```

2. Filter all containers (running + stopped)

```
docker ps -a --filter "name=nginx-gohttp-master"
```

Apparently there's no need for a wildcard character `*`, because `=` is not a direct exact-match string equality but a sub-string search.

For an exact match (which is not what you want in your question) you need to pipe the result into something else as discussed [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-filter-docker-ps-by-exact-name/2880).